# Fragment webView can't detect Google Map (Your Location)

Tags: java, android, webview, geolocation, gps

While browsing using webView, the google map failed to detect "Your location". 
How to support and enable GeoLocation on webView environment,
which can detect your location. Perhaps there's additional code i need to add on the Java? I'm using webView in a Fragment. So far, the google map itself can be load successfully.

**HomeFragment.java**

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import com.alidmisli.gcsdriver.R;
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment() {

    }

    WebView webView;
    String url = "https://google.com";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        return v;
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url)));
            } else if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url)));
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            if (uri.toString().startsWith("mailto:")) {
                //Handle mail Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri));
            } else if (uri.toString().startsWith("tel:")) {
                //Handle telephony Urls
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, uri));
            } else {
                //Handle Web Urls
                view.loadUrl(uri.toString());
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Permission Use**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Have you checked permission runtime? Because, some permissions check in runtime(like Location, Camera etc).